# SQL Query to get all rows where latest created has attribute

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of events like this

```
id    created_at   event_type      host_id   consumer_id
--------------------------------------------
1     2021-01-01   accepted        2          4
2     2021-01-02   closing         2          4
3     2021-01-01   offered         2          4
4     2021-01-01   accepted        4          3
5     2021-01-01   closing         4          3
6     2021-01-02   offered         4          3
7     2021-01-02   accepted        7          9
8     2021-01-01   closing         7          9
9     2021-01-01   offered         7          9
```

I want a query to get every row with `accepted` event_type, where the latest entry with the same `host_id` & `consumer_id`, is EITHER accepted, or closing.

("latest entry" meaning latest `created_at`)

So in the above case, I would get get back two rows.

The row with id 1 because it's `event_type` is `accepted` AND the LATEST event with it's pair of `host_id=2` and `consumer_id=4` is of type `closing`

The row with id 7 because it's `event_type` is `accepted` AND the LATEST event with it's pair of `host_id=2` and `consumer_id=4` is of type `accepted`

Conversely, I would NOT get back row 4, because even though its type IS `accepted`, the latest event with the pairing of `host_id=4` and `consumer_id=3` is of type `offered`

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: There is no `agent_id` in your data, so the question is confusing.

Comment: Good catch - updated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way using window function:

```
select * from (
   select *, first_value(event_type) over (partition by host_id,consumer_id order by created_at desc) last_event_type  
   from table 
) t
where event_type = 'accepted' and last_event_type in ('closing','accepted')
```

Comment: This is good! But I would make a slight change: add *id desc* to the *order by*  in the OVER clause. This is because each host_id, customer_id combination allows multiple events for the same date and since there is no time indication the order returned  is unpredictable and will not always return in the same order.  Better yet change the data type of created_at to timestamp. Then ordering by it will always return them in the same order. (Unless the have the same time to the micro-second then all bets are off.)